# Passing values from ViewController to multiple ViewController using objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to pass this NSString variable from

1. View Controller
2. Tab Bar Controller
3. Navigation Controller

   3.1 View Controller

I have successfully passed the value from the View Controller to the Tab Bar Controller using this code..

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:self];
```

AND

```
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loginSegue"]){
    UserTabBarViewController *uvc = segue.destinationViewController;
    uvc.resourceId = employeeId;
}
```

When I'm trying to pass the variable from step number 2 to number 3.1, the value resets to null.. I'm doing this.

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
AssignmentsTableController *add = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AssignmentsTableController"];
add.resourceId =self.resourceId;
```

after calling the line

```
add.resourceId =self.resourceId;
```

It holds the right value. but when transferring to the next ViewController. w/c in my case is AssignmentsTableController, the value resets to nil.

I have this in AssignmentsTableController..

.h file

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *resourceId;
```

.m

```
@synthesize resourceId;
```

How can i Pass values from ViewController to TabBarController to Navigation to ViewController - Objective C

Comment: Why you not try to Store values in app delegate and then use it to all over project..

Comment: You can even broadcast values to all of your view controllers using nsnotificationcenter

Comment: Best way is to create an string object within your appdelegate & access from AppDelegate instance through out the app. There are some other ways like save value in NSUserDefaults or create a singleton class with a string object.

Comment: Thanks guys, can you tell me how does that work?

Comment: here is a dirty trick. save the value using nsuserdefaults. and fetch it using nsuserdefaults from anywhere in the app